# Error with adding to lists with an Integer variable - Java

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

Say I have the class:

```
package school;
public class SchClass {
    private Student[] students;
    private int numStudents = 0;
    public SchClass() { 
    }
    public void addStudent(Student s) {
        this.students[this.numStudents] = s;
        this.amountStudents++;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to run this in another class:

```
import school.SchClass;
import school.Student;
import school.Tutor;
public class JavaTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student();
        Tutor t = new Tutor();
        SchClass shc = new SchClass();
        sch.setTutor(t);
        sch.addStudent(s);
    }
}
```

When I do this, it reports this NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at school.SchClass.addStudent(SchClass.java:8)
    at javatesting.JavaTesting.main(JavaTesting.java:10)
```

What is wrong? I'm sure I coded this perfect but it still reports an error.

Comment: initialize `Student[] students` array

Comment: try to at least syntax check code examples if they are supposed to be complete code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

member students is null

```
  public class SchClass {
        private Student[] students = new Student[ size ];
        private int numStudents = 0;
        public SchClass() { 
        }
        public void addStudent(Student s) {
            this.students[this.numStudents] = s;
            this.amountStudents++;
        }
    }
```

and it will work only untils amountStudents < size, then execption will occur so better is

```
public class SchClass {
    private List< Student > students = new ArrayList< Student >();
    public SchClass() { 
    }
    public void addStudent(Student s) {
        this.students.add( s );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [Collection framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html). If you want dynamic "arrays" you may use `List<T>`

Arrays are not dynamic.

Also, you have numerous errors in your class. What is for example `this.amountStudents++` supposed to do? Furthermore I am surprised that your code does not already fail at `sch.setTutor(t);`, since you do not have declared a variable called `sch`. Did you mean `shc`?